# Verbatim search in azure/cognitive/bing web search (API, not website)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, bing, bing-api

I cannot find any option to achieve a verbatim azure/cognitive/bing Web search.

In my case the difference is trying to sift through tens of millions of irrelevant search results to find the 10 results that actually match my query literally.

Even though I am a paying customer, there is no support available. And the API documentation did not help either.

I would think it should be super easy to provide a verbatim search option. Is there one that I did not see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked further and it seems for the Bing Search APIs - **+"phrase"** works and returns documents containing this phrase at the top. Just add **+** in front of what you have been trying. Support link is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/.

Comment: Thanks! I meant I pay 30 USD/mo for the Bing API but this does not include any support requests. So I cannot contact support without upgrading to that.

Comment: What do you think is the reason why verbatim search modes are not offered?

Comment: Well, "query" was meant for that. However, search engines drop some stop words/numbers/symbols and do a lot of other things to understand which words are important. With this preprocessing, it is difficult to guarantee word occurrences - even if you have a separate option for that.